# How to get rid of warning message that is displayed when user tries to open Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using version 3.17 of the Apache POI library to create an Excel spreadsheet in Java. When the user downloads it from the server and attempts to open the spreadsheet, a warning message is displayed. I am thinking that the format of the spreadsheet is somehow not correct. How do I fix it so that the user will not see that message? It is important to note that the spreadsheet opens fine, and all the data is there.

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet spreadsheet;

// Add rows and cells to spreadsheet

response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=sheet.xls");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
workbook.write(bos);
bos.close();

try (InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray())) {
  IOUtils.copy(stream, response.getOutputStream());
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extension should be `.xlsx`, not `.xls`